# IntelliJ: Overriding new java version did not work

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project where I want to use `Java v 1.7`, so I made the change in my project for Java Compiler
[image]
and maven compiler as
[image]

But still When I deploy my JBoss application via IntelliJ I see error like

```
13:04:24,295 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class com.myorg.bb.business.LoginManager in Module "deployment.web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/myorg/bb/business/LoginManager : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [classes.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [classes.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [classes.jar:1.6.0_29]
```

How can I make this work with Java v1.7?

Comment: Do you have a Java 7 JDK installed?

Comment: Yes, I do have it installed

Comment: JBoss may be still running under JDK 1.6 as its launcher script gets the JDK from `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Make sure your system environment is correct and JBoss is started under JDK 1.7. You may need to adjust the startup script manually as tweaking environment on Mac OS X is tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `JAVA_HOME` is set to 1.7, you may try to [override it in the JBoss Run/Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eezxI.png) configuration in IntelliJ IDEA as [setting environment on Mac is tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) and depends on the OS version.

Comment: You saved me a lot of pain, @CrazyCoder ! 
Thanks!